# Detecting elements in a group using characters.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

It is well known that the trace of the regular representation $\rho$ of a group $G$ 'detects' the identity element of the group. More precisely, we have

$$
Tr(\rho)(g) = \begin{cases}|G|&\mbox{if }g=e\\
0&\mbox{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$

Now, if $G$ is Abelian, this can be used to detect arbitrary elements in $G$ as

\begin{equation}\label{Equation 1}
Tr(\rho)(h^{-1}g) = \begin{cases}|G|&\mbox{if }g=h\\
0&\mbox{otherwise.}\end{cases}
\end{equation}

The key here is that every irreducible representation of $G$ (in this case) is one dimensional so that $Tr(\rho)(h^{-1}g) = \rho(h^{-1}g)$ can be written as a linear combination of irreducible representations of $G$.

My question is the following.

**Is there an analogous way to detect arbitrary elements when $G$ is non Abelian**

**EDIT:** Let me add some context to why I am asking this question. The motivation comes from Artin $L$ functions (over $\mathbb{Q}$ for simplicity). Consider the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ and suppose, for a fixed $a,N\in \mathbb{N}$ with $GCD(a,N)=1$, I am interested in the function
$$
L(s):=\sum_{m\equiv a\mod N} \frac{1}{m^s}.
$$
Then it is well known (and in fact a consequence of the first of the two equations above) that

$$
L(s) = \frac{1}{\varphi(N)}\sum_\chi \chi(a)^{-1}L(s,\chi)
$$
where $L(s,\chi)$ is the Dirichlet $L$ function of the character $\chi$ modulo $N$, given by

$$
L(s,\chi) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi(n)}{n^s},
$$
and the summation runs over all characters of $(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^\times$.

Something very similar can be done for other number fields as well (although I have not done the exact calculations, I think it should be possible to do the same for other Dirichlet/Hecke $L$ functions too). Now I am interested in replacing $\zeta(s)$ with Artin $L$ functions of representations of higher dimensions and see if something similar is possible. I hope this makes my question clear.

Comment: Your formula for ${\rm tr}\,\rho(h^{-1}g)$ is true regardless of if $G$ is abelian or not.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, the point is that characters are class functions, so in a non-abelian group you will not be able to distinguish two distinct elements that are conjugate.

Comment: Please read my edit

Answer (score 3):

Irrespective of the abelianess of $G$, the regular character over the complex numbers for finite groups at least, is defined in a similar way:
$$\rho=\underset{\chi \in Irr(G)}\sum \chi(1)\chi.$$
And $\rho(g)=|G|$ if $g=1$, $\rho(g)=0$, if $g \neq 1$. Hence similarly, this character can “detect” arbitrary elements.

**Edit** (April 8th 2021)

As you probably know, Richard Dedekind studied the quotients of what are now called [Dedekind zeta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_zeta_function) and proved that the quotient $\zeta_M(s)/\zeta(s)$ is entire for every pure cubic extension $M/\mathbb{Q}$. This result suggests that the quotient $\zeta_M(s)/\zeta_k(s)$ of Dedekind zeta functions is entire whenever $M/k$ is an extension of number fields, and this is now called the *Dedekind conjecture*.

Somewhat differently, for any $G = Gal(K/k)$, Artin conjectured that every $L$-function $L(s, \chi, K/k)$ with $\chi \in Irr(G)-\{1_G\}$,  extends to an entire function. Artin Reciprocity Law implies this conjecture is valid if $\chi$ is monomial, that is, induced from a linear character of some subgroup of $G$. From this and his famous induction theorem, Brauer further showed that each $L(s, \chi, K/k)$ extends to a meromorphic function over $\mathbb{C}$. Aramata and Brauer independently proved the Dedekind conjecture for every Galois extension of number fields. Furthermore, if $M$ is contained in a solvable normal closure of $k$, Uchida and Robert van der Waall established (1975) the Dedekind conjecture in this case. In general, the Dedekind conjecture would follow from Artin’s conjecture. However, both conjectures are still open.

I hope this provides you with more background and reading.

Comment: Please read my edit